# Salt-stack working with Pam.d

Tags: regex, linux, sed, salt-stack, rhel6

All systems running `RHEL6`
So, My end goal is to be able to have state controlled pam configuration(`system-auth`, and `password-auth`). That also doesn't interfere with changes that might need to happen on a local system to system basis.

Essentially I want to add lines to the pam config files for things like `pam_cracklib` without having to just overwrite the entire file with `file.managed`

example of current `system-auth`(not a full example, some items removed)

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so  try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 100 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow  try_first_pass use_authtok remember=24
password    required      pam_deny.so
```

An example problem:

I need the line:

```
password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 dcredit=-1 minlen=12 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=-1 difok=3
```

to appear, with those settings, above the `password` line of the `pam_unix.so` entry like so:

```
password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 dcredit=-1 minlen=12 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=-1 difok=3
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow  try_first_pass use_authtok remember=24
```

In some cases, `pam_cracklib` may already exist, and I can simply use `file.replace` state to find the `pattern` for `pam_cracklib` and replace it with the good line. In other cases, pam_cracklib may need to be added, and as such the limitation with `file.replace` of `appending` or `prepending` causes problems.

Another example would be `pam_faillock.so` which needs to be inserted on very specific lines. IE before or after other pam modules of importance.

I've considered just biting the bullet and using `file.managed` to enforce a unified pam file to my systems, and then making exceptions as needed to keep the other things functional, but these feels a lot like painting myself into a corner.

Any suggestions on a method of dealing with specific item location placements, without enforcing an entire file? In `sed` I can can use `()`'s along with the escape's `\1`, `\2` to keep parts of a pattern, and combined with `newlines` and what not, I can look for a pattern and replace text above or below a line, and move on. But as far as I can tell that can't be done with `file.replace`. I suppose I could simply issue a `sed` command with `cmd.run` but then I have to be annoyed by the fact that it will run every time states are enforced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I heard [Auegas](http://augeas.net/) is supposed to address generic read-write access to various configuration files - [Salt has its module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.augeas.html). There is a [PAM lense](http://augeas.net/docs/references/lenses/files/pam-aug.html).
- Another pointer is [`file.managed`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html) with `marker_start` and `marker_end` parameters. This approach works perfectly for simple configurations like [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) where manually maintained part is separated from automatically enforced one.

---

**GENERAL NOTES**

It is fundamentally difficult problem to support syntax of various configuration files on the system for automatic modification. Templates fully overriding destination files provide generic approach with limitations you stated. The generic approach explodes in complexity if it is required to read the destination file and apply conditionally some modifications to the its original content.

Think about automatically changing (manually written) source code while maintaining its readability and guaranteeing semantically correct runtime after that, do it for all top 10 programming languages.

Even if general format is simple (e.g. text lines), there is still a problem to satisfy expectations of the software which consumes this configuration. Does the order of lines matter? Will duplicated lines be illegal? Should comments be preserved?